# Product of Array Except Self (Leetcode)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

```
class Solution {
    public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
        
        //Approach: Using prefix and postfix
        //Idea: Just find prefix and postfix product and keep them in the ans array

        int ans[] = new int[nums.length];
        int pre = 1, post = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++) {
            ans[i] = pre;
            pre*=nums[i];
        }

        for(int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0;i--) {
            ans[i] *= post;
            post*=nums[i];
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Hello guys, I would like to know what is the 2 loops are doing. Because I manually count it and my answer is incorrect.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [24,12,8,6]

Based on my calculation, the first for loop will then create [1,2,6,24]. (not sure correct or wrong).
second for loop i dont seems to get the correct output. (it might be my first loop also went wrong?)
Appreciate if you can solve my problem.

Comment: "not sure correct or wrong" - isn't the best approach to add some diagnostics or debug through the code so you can see what's going on then? (As an aside, I'd strongly advise you not to use the `int ans[]` style of declaring arrays - keep all the type information together, so `int[] ans`.)

Comment: *"the first for loop will then create [1,2,6,24]"*: no, it will not. Just use a debugger and step through the code inspecting variables. It should be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two loops here are for calculating :

- 1st loop - Product of array element on left side of current element
- 2nd Loop - Product of array element on right side of current element

After 1st Loop, ans[] -> [1,1,2,6]

Then in 2nd loop, you start from reverse side, and multiplying ans[] with product of element on right, as below :

```
[1,1,2,6*1] -> [1,1,2*4, 6*1] -> [1, 1*12, 2*4, 6*1] -> [1*24, 1*12, 2*4, 6*1]

= [24, 12, 8, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it is calculating from reverse side and also your working. This answer really solve my doubts and I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach may be to get the product of the entire array, and then iterate over the array again and divide it by each element:

```java
public int[] productExceptSelf(int[] nums) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        product *= nums[i];
    }

    int[] result = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        result[i] = product / nums[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The question does not allow to use division.

Answer (score 0):

> the first for loop will then create [1,2,6,24]

No, it will not produce that for the given input [1,2,3,4]. Realise that the value of `pre` is **first** assigned to `ans[i]` and only **then** it is multiplied. So the value 24 (which is the final product stored in `pre`) will never be written to the answer.

Just step through the code and we get these states **at the end** of each iteration

| `i` | `ans[i]` | `nums[i]` | `pre` (product) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 6 | 4 | 24 |

What you thought would be in `ans` is actually what the values of `pre` are at the end of the iteration, but `ans[i]` is assigned the value of `pre` *before* the latter is updated.

Hope this clarifies how that code correctly calculates the expected result.